# node_moduleライブラリのjsファイルでimport，export等が使用されている場合にbrowserifyする方法

Tags: typescript, browserify

browserify APIを利用してTypeScriptで書かれたコードをJavaScriptに変換し、それらのコードを一つにまとめる処理を書いています。
以下が問題が発生するコードです。

```
(async () => {

    let code = await (() => {
        const browserifyObject = browserify();
        browserifyObject.add(`${__dirname}/game.js`);
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            browserifyObject.bundle((error, source) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }
                const code = new TextDecoder().decode(source);
                resolve(code);
            });
        });
    })();

    // いろいろ処理

})();
```

> エラーログ

```
[SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'] {
  line: 1,
  column: 1,
  annotated: '\n' +
    (省略)\\node_modules\\three\\examples\\jsm\\controls\\OrbitControls.js:1\n
```

3Dライブラリ Three.js 内のファイルである `OrbitControls.js` にて JavaScript で書かれたコードの中に `import` が使用されているためエラーが発生したことは理解しましたが、それを解決する方法から見つからず、一向に進むことができません。
エラー内容に書いてある指示に従って、`sourceType`プロパティを`module`にしましたが、エラー内容が変わることはありませんでした。ご教授お願いします。

Comment: babelifyなどで変換させてやることで問題は解決できるはずですが、もし新規にBrowserifyを採用しているのであれば（あるいは新規でなくても）本当にそれが適切な選択かは考え直すべきかもしれません。これらは既にほぼメンテされていないプロジェクトです。（最近主流のモジュールバンドらはネイティブにesmをサポートしているものが多く、ライブラリもそれ前提となっているものがふえています。）

Comment: そうなってくると、どの様なbrowserify代用ライブラリを使用すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 有名どころのバンドラーとしては esbuild, rollup, vite(前2つのラッパー), Parcel, Webpackなどがあります。用途次第なところはあるかと思うのでそのあたりは要確認です。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。ありがとうございますm(__)m

Answer (score 0):

browserifyはプロジェクト自体があまり動いていないので、一度ほんの少しだけ使用したことがあるWebpackを採用することにしました。【コメントより】
ありがとうございました。